# Facebook API mutual_friends request and Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm using the Facebook SDK (v3.16) in my iOS application, and everything is working fine on the login side. However, I'm trying to add a mutual friends type feature where users can see how many mutual friends they share with other users, through Facebook. The app is targeted at college students, so most of my users share a lot of mutual friends. I started out by trying it straight in code, and I got some weird numbers. Almost all the mutual friend counts were at 0.

Then I went to Graph Explorer API, and using a scoped facebook ID from my app, along with my app's access token, I entered this into the tester:

```
--->/v2.2/10152467114358576?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)
```

So the ID there is a scoped facebook ID for someone who is NOT my friend on facebook, but has accepted the user_friends privilege on my application. I am another user of the app, and have also accepted the user_friends privilege. The result of the above line was:

```
{
"id": "10152467114358576" 
}
```

When it should be more something like this (we have 10 mutual friends, but only 1 of them is on my app) :

```
{
 "context": {
  "mutual_friends": {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "XXXXX", 
      "name": "Mutual Friend on my App"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTAyMDQyMTAxNjA2NDYzOTU=", 
      "after": "MTAyMDQ0MjI2NzMwMDA5MjI="
    }
  }, 
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 10
  }
 }
}, 
"id": "10152467114358576"
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you figured it out by now? For me, mutual_likes works, but mutual_friends does not give any result...

Comment: See accepted response.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the answer, did you get to the point where you at least got a mutual friends count back under the right circumstances or have you basically given up on the feature?

Comment: Since it was not supported by Facebook I gave up on the feature and moved on

Comment: Thanks... Such a shame they´ve removed the functionality with 2.0 :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I'm trying to do is just not supported by the API. I posted a bug to Facebook, and got this response:

```
The docs [1] say "A valid user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the mutual friends of other friends using the app."
This implies that the session user, and the person against whom you are checking mutual friendships have to be friends as well.
```

What this means is since two users on my app are not necessarily friends, some mutual friend counts will be there and many will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing as I have no access to an iOS dev environment, but what hits my eye is that you use an old version of the iOS SDK with the most actual Graph API calls (v2.2). I'd suggest you try to update the iOS SDK to the most recent version and test again.

- Release date iOS SDK: July 10th, 2014
- Release date Graph API v2.2: October 30th, 2014

Answer (score -1):

Unlike the previous version of Graph API, in the v2.0 and above, facebook reveals friend edges only when both the users have given access to your app. So users who have not given permission to your app may not show up in the mutual friends list.

Comment: Yes, but the summary should have all the users mutual friends, no? There is no summary

Comment: I also explicitly stated in my question that both users had accepted my user friends privilege